# Retrieving a value from a Label is NaN after parsing to a float

Tags: javascript, nan, parsefloat

I need to convert a sales price from EUR to GBP, so I'm attempting to divide the sales price by the exchange rate but it keeps coming up as NaN!

```
var xRate = $('#MainContent_lblCurrency').text();  //The value is "1.12350" when alerted out
//xRate = "1.23345";

alert("EXC Rate is " + xRate);  //this is fine
totalEurPrice = totalEurPrice.toFixed(numDecPoints);
alert("totalEurPrice is " + totalEurPrice);  //this is fine
//now we divide to get GBP sales value
var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalEurPrice) / parseFloat(xRate);  //this gives NaN
```

If I uncomment the line, xRate = "1.23345"; it all works fine.  Please can someone tell me why it doesn't work when I retrieve the value from a label (which is presumably returned as a string)??

Comment: Obviously the text value of the `MainContent_lblCurrency` element is not parseable as a number. An alert would not normally add double quotes, so perhaps the problem is that the value has actual quote characters around it? Try `alert('"' + xRate + '"')`. Or use `console.log` instead, it's better practice.

Comment: or `totalEurPrice` is not parseable.

Comment: can you give the totalEurPrice output?

Comment: Is `totalEurPrice` already a number (int, float) before you use `toFixed`? Just make sure all the numbers are indeed numbers, and not strings: https://jsfiddle.net/x2qfeyop/2/

Comment: There's too much missing information here. Please try to make a working example of the problem with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sorry for late reply (was taken off to another project).  Anyway, when I run it and do a view source, this is what I get:  <span id="MainContent_lblCurrency"><strong>Exchange_Rate: </strong>1.12350</span>, so it looks like the value should return "<strong>Exchange_Rate: </strong>1.12350</span>" but when I alert it out, I get 1.12350.  Bit confused by this but anyway I guess I need to leave out the text within the <strong> tags.  Will try that now :-)

Comment: Yes it works perfectly - feel a bit stupid now lol!

Answer (score 0):

As already everyone said there is lack of info.So I have made few assumptions based on current statistics.

i)var totalEurPrice=74.7888987;

ii)var numDecPoints=2;

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var xRate = $('#MainContent_lblCurrency').text();//Just check this once again,I am skeptical about this line.
    var totalEurPrice=74.7888987;
    var numDecPoints=2;
    alert("EXC Rate is " + xRate);//Pops up  1.23345
    totalEurPrice = totalEurPrice.toFixed(numDecPoints);
    alert("totalEurPrice is " + totalEurPrice);  //Pops up 74.79
    //now we divide to get GBP sales value
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalEurPrice) / parseFloat(xRate); 
    alert(totalPrice);//Pops up 60.63480481576068         
                           });
```

Hope this helps :)